# Understanding uploading files

Tags: php, html

I apologize for the super long post. I'm super noob and I would LOVE to have your help.

I made a file called `Upload Pictures` and in this file I have four files. First, `php.ini` with the following code:

```
file_uploads = On
```

Second, `upload.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Third, `upload.php`:

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
?>
```

And fourth, I have a folder called `uploads`, with nothing inside that folder.

My main questions are from the `upload.php` file. Please correct me if I am incorrect in my understanding.

I understand `$target_dir` to be the directory in which the files will be stored. Now to the line with `&target_file`. I understand  that `$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]` returns the name of the file that I am uploading. So if my file name was `picture.jpg`, it will return `picture.jpg`.

My question is then, why do I need to call the `basename()`? Because I thought this function just returns the name of the file. So it's almost like returning the name twice with `$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]` and `basename()`?

Also, it has been my experience that having a `.` and some function after is calling a method from a class. Is that what is happening here `$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);`? If so, I'm not sure what is actually being stored into `$target_file`.

Also, switching gears a little bit here, when I pressed the `Upload Image` button from my `html`, it takes me to another page. Is there a way to prevent that from happening?

Comment: basename=pointless; dot = concatenation nothing to do with classes(oop).

Comment: "Upload Image" takes you to the url you put in the form action, that can be any page you like

Comment: The "dot" `.` means concatenation. Or, combining two values. Also, Basename() practically strips the directory information. Eg: if you have "example.jpg" it will return "example"

Comment: target file =`uploads/file_name_of_uploaded_file`

Answer (score 4):

[basename](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) returns the actual filename from a path.

In your example basename does not need to be used on the name being retrieved from [$_FILES](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php) because it will have no associated path to begin with. In an upload script basename may be more traditionally used on `tmp_name` to remove any temporary folders from the name of the file.

The `.` is how you [concatenate](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) strings (or in this case variables containing strings) in PHP.

In this example, the code is concatenating the directory and the name of the file together into a variable in which it is used to get the extension in the `$imageFileType` variable using [pathinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php).

The form has an action attribute. `action="upload.php"` so you will be taken to the 'upload.php' page when the form is submitted.

I hope this answers your questions-

Comment: awesome. Thank you so much. Um... is there a way to prevent my  page from going to the upload.php page?

Comment: You can do this by removing the 'action' attribute from the form element all together.

Comment: But then how do I access the upload.php?

Answer (score 1):

actually `basename()` function for get file name **with the extension of file**.

so `basename` function stand for

```
basename(path,suffix)
```

Explanation

```
Parameter   |   Description
--------------------------
path        |   Required. Specifies the path to check
suffix      |   Optional. Specifies a file extension. If the filename has this file extension, the file extension will not show
```

Ex

```
<?php
    $path = "/testweb/home.php";

    //Show filename with file extension
    echo basename($path) ."<br/>";

   //Show filename without file extension
    echo basename($path,".php");
?>
```

Output will be

```
home.php
home
```

[php 5 `basename()` function](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_basename.asp)

and we use `.` (`dot`) operator on here, `$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);`

so this will bind `$target_dir` and `basename()`. so `$target_file` knows where is file should be goes exactly.